# Haskell IO code doesn't typecheck

Tags: haskell, io, monads, typechecking

I'm a beginner with Haskell and am having trouble figuring out some code.  What do I need to do to get the types right on this IO section of my code?

Thanks in advance.

```
loadPeople :: FilePath -> IO [Person]
loadPeople file = do
   lines <- getLines file
   map parsePerson lines

getLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getLines = liftM lines . readFile

parsePerson :: String -> Person
parsePerson line = ...........
```

`map` is underlined in red in Leksah, and the compile error I am receiving is:

```
src\Main.hs:13:3:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO [Person]'
           against inferred type `[Person]'
    In the expression: map parsePerson lines
    In the expression:
        do { lines <- getLines file;
             map parsePerson lines }
    In the definition of `loadPeople':
        loadPeople file
                     = do { lines <- getLines file;
                            map parsePerson lines }
```

Comment: You could eliminate the "getLines" function by using Functors (see: http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids). You can do: "ls <- fmap lines $ readFile file"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map parsePerson lines` has type `[Person]`, but since you need the result type of `loadPeople` is `IO [Person]`, you need to wrap it in `IO` using `return`:

```
return $ map parsePerson lines
```

Comment: YES! Thanks. That makes total sense, now that I think of it.

Comment: Seriously late comment: Better to write this as `liftM (parsePerson lines) $ getLines file`. Keep it mind that whenever you have a two line monadic function theres usually a better way to write it.